# jqXHR responseText equivalent in Angular 2 http

Tags: jquery, angular, http, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

In a jQuery ajax request I can call

```
.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    return jqXHR.responseText;
});
```

when the request fails. And it gives me the response the server has set.

I would like to ask what is the exact equivalent of this `responseText` in Angular 2 HttpClient.

I can get the response like this:

```
http.get(url).map(response => {

});
```

Comment: `response.text()` ?

Comment: I don't know, there is also a `response.statusText` and I dont want to get the whole as a text when it has not failed.

Comment: [statusText](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Response/statusText) is like `"Forbidden"` for 403 error. On the other hand `response.text()` is the response body as string.

Comment: It seems that jQuery responseText and response.text() they return the same. I was trying to search for a proof that these two are equivalent, but did not find. If you have one, feel free to answer.